# Proxy to Java app

Tags: java, apache, proxy

I have a java application running on a server IP 1.1.1.1 port 111
I have an Apache server running on IP 1.1.1.2 port 80

Apache should be configured as a proxy.

Clients will configure their computers to point to my Apache proxy at 1.1.1.2 port 80

The question is could i configure the Apache server to redirect the requests  coming from the client to the java app for processing and if the java app sees that it should deny the request then it will inform Apache and Apache by its turn should informs the client.

Am i dreaming or this could be implemented?

Any suggestions would be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. Have a look at the mod_proxy plugin for Apache. There are a few security and implementation considerations to cover, such as:

- Is the site to be accessed via a new virtual host defined in Apache, or an existing one?
- HTTP vs HTTPs access? (From your post, it seems like the decision is to use HTTP port 80)
- What URL(s) to match on for the proxy rule to trigger?
- Is the access allowed from all IP ranges or only a particular subnet?
- Is there a benefit in offloading some of the static resources to the Apache server to ease the load on the backend application server, or using a mod_deflate to gzip the resources before forwarding them to the clients?

  [mod_proxy documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)

Comment: The things is i'm making an app that will block porn. So, the app will be installed on a phone and the phone should count on the proxy for all kinds of interaction with the web. The important point is that i have to set up a global proxy for the phone and when the user enters a url the request must go to the proxy and the proxy will redirect the request to the java app and java will decide whether to approve or deny.